# How to save object in django database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am creating models in django, **i need a field** to save object, for eg to save a string django has CharField, i have api which returns me object and i want to create a model to save this object. I checked django models fields but didn't find any field to save object.

**Is there any field to save an object in django database?**

**models.py**

```
class UnusedResources(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    saveobject = Field to save an object ?
```

Comment: Have you tried calling .save() on the object?

Comment: I think question was miss understood, that's why it was voted negatively

Comment: Mine Question is if i have an object and i want to store it in my database like we do for string, integer then what should i need to do,  look at my `models.py`.

Comment: In this case you want to look into relationships. I'll post an example answer shortly, but I have to ask: do you have previous experience with databases (especially using SQL, not just an ORM)?

Comment: yes i have, i know about the relationships.

Comment: I posted an answer, I hope it helps you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A model in Django is supposed to correlate to a table in the database, so that each field in the model will actually be a field in the table for that model.

To achieve what you're trying to do, you need to create a second model, which will be the object you want to store.

```
from django.db import models

class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
```

The code above was taken from [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/), which you should definitely read for more details.

Now back to your question, the field `artist` inside the `Album` model, is actually the kind of "object" field you are looking for (it's actually a reference to another object, or a Foreign Key).

```
musician = Musician.objects.create(
    first_name="My", last_name="Name", instrument="guitar")
album = Album.objects.create(
    name="Great Album", release_date=date, num_stars=5, artist=musician)
```

As you can see, I created a `Musician` object called `musician`, and saved it to the database. Next, I created an `Album` object, which takes the object `musician` into it's `artist` field, and saved it into the database.

In the database, our album entry contains an `artist_id` field, whose value is the ID of our `musician` object created above.

So basically, just like we create tables for each entity we have in a database, in Django we use models, and each model corresponds to a specific table.

Comment: Thanks, i was reading the docs and i think now i understand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To save an object as your model field you need to first serialize it and then you can save it like this:

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class UnusedResources(models.Model):
    # other fields 
    obj = models.TextField()
```

views.py:

```
from django.core import serializers

def basic_func():            
    obj = MyModel.objects.create(text="some text...") # create object of MyModel.        
    s_obj = serializers.serialize("json", [obj]) # convert object to json format          
    obj2 = UnusedResources.objects.create(obj=s_obj) # save it to other model         
    print obj2.obj # accessing the model.
```

for more about serializers please visit [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/)